# Dockerfile cloning from private gitlab with ssh and deploy key

Tags: ssh, docker, git, gitlab

(EDIT) This problem was happening also from my laptop using root and my user, which could get the greeting when trying to ssh with git user. Then tried the ansible playbook and it raised errors for the repo too. Tried another one and that clones flawlessly. The problem, then, doesn't seem to be with git, docker or ssh, but with the gitlab configuration.

---

On a Dockerfile I am trying to c**lone private repositories hosted on a company server running gitlab and setup with a non standard ssh port**.

This is what I expected to run (alongside with some params in ssh config file)

```
RUN git clone git@companyname.ddns.net:GroupName/repo_name.git
```

Things I've checked already:

- The repo has a deploy key and it is active.
- Automating with Ansible instead of docker, it can connect and clone repos.
- The key is named id_rsa and it is inside ~/.ssh/
- Tried with ssh-agent and seems ok (though I specify the file in the config and shouldn't need it)

  ```
  Identity added: /opt/.ssh/id_rsa (/opt/.ssh/id_rsa)
  ```
- The ~/.ssh/config has the following:

  ```
  Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
    PasswordAuthentication no
    User git
    ForwardAgent yes
    Identityfile /opt/.ssh/id_rsa # /opt is the home of the user RUNning the command in docker
    port 22022
  ```

RUNning this from the container:

```
ssh -vT -i /opt/.ssh/id_rsa git@companyname.ddns.net:GroupName/repo_name.git
```

Gets the result

> Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!

But the git clone command gets:

```
Cloning into 'repo_name'...
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
and the repository exists.
The command '/bin/sh -c git clone git@companyname.ddns.net:GroupName/repo_name.git;' returned a non-zero code: 128
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is `~/.ssh/config` ? Docker builds are done as root so that config would need to be in `/root/.ssh/config`

Comment: It is in /opt/.ssh/config . /opt being the home of the user I expect to run the git clone, after USER user_name. Ownership is explicitly changed and so are permissions, set to 400

Comment: Hoping this was the problem, added the config file to both /opt/.ssh and /root/.ssh. The problem remains the same, sadly.